# check if sql job is running

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have stored procedure that calls a sql job but the job is failing if 2 users make a call to the stored procedure at the same time so here is what I want to do:

1. check if sql job is running first
2. only execute the 2nd call if the first call finishes.

I have seen some examples where you can find out if job is running but can't seem to find out to put the 2nd call on hold and only execute when the first one completes.

```
DECLARE @job_name NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'mySQLJob'
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = @mySQLJob
```

the error I am getting is something like "job is already running"

Comment: See [sp_help_job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186722.aspx)

Comment: You might want to do this by using transactions (and other mechanisms) to ensure that updates are getting the proper locks.  Whatever the SP is doing, another SP could do or someone could do manually . . . and your prevention mechanism won't be of any use.

Comment: What does the job do? Does it have to be a job?

Comment: [`sp_getapplock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) can be used to have a second instance of the job detect another running instance and either exit or wait.

Answer (score 4):

sp_help_job can give you this information

```
EXEC msdb..sp_help_job @job_name = 'mySQLJob', @job_aspect = 'JOB'
```

current_execution_status Values
 - 1 Executing
 - 2 Waiting For Thread 
 - 3 Between Retries 
 - 4 Idle 
 - 5 Suspended
 - 6 Obsolete 
 - 7 PerformingCompletionActions